# GA client ID is getting changed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In my site when a client lands a page the GA tracking that client correctly but clientId is getting changed when navigating to next page and the client is considering as direct user. I got this report by analyzing data from Google Analytics.

This is occurring in only for IE browser (version 9, 10 & 11).

I tried a day to generate this manually in my machine but didn't.

Could you please help me to know what is the problem is or what might be?

Note: My GA is configured by GTM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [this document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id), we known that the GA client id is a unique, randomly generated string that gets stored in the browsers cookies, so please check the cookie expire time.

Besides, using cookies allows analytics.js to identify unique users across browsing sessions, but it cannot identify unique users across different browsers or devices. If your site has its own authentication system, you can use the **User ID** feature, in addition to the Client ID, to more accurately identify a user across all the devices they use to access your site.

Answer (score 0):

As such if the clientID changes this indicates that GA considers it a new session. This is commonly caused by:
- The Domain changed (or it is explicitly set within the cookieDomain).
- The GA cookie is no longer present (expired?)

To resolve I would use the output of the GA debug console.